# how to create drop down list using Mootools?

Tags: javascript

I want to add drop down list to my form (onclick event of a button).
I know this is basic of JS.
But Please Help!
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: by dropdown do you mean a simple `<select>` box?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example [here](http://www.php-help.ro/mootools-12-javascript-examples/javascript-drop-down-menu-using-mootools-12/) including all of the necessary HTML, Javascript and CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-container">
<ul id="drop_down_menu">
    <li class="menu">Menu 1
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">Menu 2
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
$('drop_down_menu').getElements('li.menu').each( function( elem ){
    var list = elem.getElement('ul.links');
    var myFx = new Fx.Slide(list).hide();
    elem.addEvents({
        'mouseenter' : function(){
            myFx.cancel();
            myFx.slideIn();
        },
        'mouseleave' : function(){
            myFx.cancel();
            myFx.slideOut();
        }
    });
})
});
```